# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int - when calling a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, return

I have a simple stored procedure that takes one input of an INT. The procedure also declares one value (@KEY) as a VARCHAR. The logic of the procedure sets the value of the @KEY to an alphanumeric value.

Finally, the procedure returns the value of @KEY:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_KEY]

@member     Int

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @KEY        VARCHAR(12)

    SET @KEY = ''

    IF Exists (Select * From Version Where NAME = 'WIN' AND MEMBER = @member)
        Begin
            Set @KEY = '95+'
        End

    RETURN @KEY 

END  -- END OF PROCEDURE
```

When I call the procedure using:

Declare @return_key Varchar(20)
exec @return_key = dbo.sp_Get_KEY 2222

I receive the following error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '95+E' to data type int.

Any ideas?

Comment: And what if you just use `exec dbo.sp_Get_KEY 2222` ?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use out parameter or the resulset to return any data type.
Return values should always be integer

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Get_KEY]
     @member     Int
    ,@KEY VARCHAR(12) OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 --DECLARE @KEY        VARCHAR(12)

 SET @KEY = ''

 IF Exists (Select * From Version Where NAME = 'WIN' AND MEMBER = @member)
    Begin
        Set @KEY = '95+'
    End

 RETURN 0; 
END
```

Example :

```
declare @KEY VARCHAR(12);  
exec dbo.sp_Get_KEY 2222, @KEY OUTPUT;  
--SELECT @KEY;  
PRINT @KEY;
```

Comment: Thank-you. How would I call this from SQL - what would be the syntax in specifying the output parameter?

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to avoid the 'SELECT' statement as I am calling this stored procedure from within another stored procedure that uses the return value of the first to perform some other logic - which is then being called within code. If I use the 'SELECT' statement, multiple record sets are returned that then breaks the code.

Comment: the "SELECT" is just like example the value is in the variable